# Is it possible to check a dynamic path in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I would like to know if it is possible to dynamically loop through paths in a a jira object and print the value if it doesn't match ?

I have two objects, with have a bunch of fields....

jira_object_1

```
{
    "key": "3000",
    "fields": {
        "customfield_14550": null,
        "customfield_12770": null,
        "customfield_11441": "2023-07-13T12:45:00.000+0200",
        "customfield_12772": null,
        "customfield_14444": null,
        "customfield_10120": null,
        "customfield_12941": null,
        "customfield_14445": null,
        "customfield_12940": null,
        "customfield_14446": null,
        "due_date": null
    }
}
```

I have this little script which is supposed to check all the paths that are different between the two jira ticket objects.

```
keys = {
     # path and description
    ("fields.customfield_14550", "name-1"),
    ("fields.customfield_12770", "name-2"),
    ("fields.customfield_11441", "name-3"),
    ("fields.customfield_12772", "name-4"),
    ("fields.customfield_14444", "name-5"),
    ("fields.customfield_10120", "name-6"),
    ("fields.customfield_12941", "name-7"),
    ("fields.customfield_14445", "name-8"),
    ("fields.customfield_12940", "name-9"),
    ("fields.customfield_14446", "name-10"),
    ("fields.due_date", "date")
}

for key in keys:
    path, description = key
    if jira_object_1.get(path) != jira_object_1.get(path):
        print('---')
        print(description, path)
        print('---')
```

However, when I use the get() method on the object it fails, I can't seem to get a value out of it.
output

```
--->
None
None
--->
--->
None
None
--->
--->
None
None
--->
```

and I can't seem to do convert the jira ticket object to a dictionary as it is not serializable.

```
command:
srcDict = json.dumps(list(jira_object_1))

                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
error: 
TypeError: 'Issue' object is not iterable
```

```
command:
srcDict = json.dumps(jira_object_1)

error:
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Issue is not JSON serializable
```

Why is that?

Comment: Please, post [mre] as well as full traceback verbatim. your so called `dicts` are NOT `dicts` at all, but probably `json` strings.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but right now you are comparing the path to itself: if jira_object_1.get(path) != jira_object_1.get(path)
  The second one should be object_2

Comment: Can you add the code that gets the jira object?

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method can only be used on dictionaries, not on tuples.

In your loop, `key` is a tuple containing the path and description, so you need to access the dictionaries `dict1` and `dict2` separately using those paths to get their values:

```py
for path, description in keys:
    value1 = dict1["fields"].get(path)
    value2 = dict2["fields"].get(path)

    if value1 != value2:
        print('---')
        print(description, path)
        print('---')

        print('--->')
        print(value1)
        print(value2)
        print('--->')
```

Also in python the null value is actually `None`, not `null`, you might need to change that in your dictionaries.

Comment: The jira object isn't serializable and can't seem to convert if to a standard dict.   I will not be able to use the get object it seems until I figure out how to get the dict.... The python Jira object and it may mean that I make api request instead of the jira module.

Answer (score 0):

Following your description of the data, it looks like you have a json string and a set of key value pairs not dictionaries. However we can still work with them.

Let's start by turning your json string into a dictionary.

```py
import json

jira_object_1 = """
{
    "key": "3000",
    "fields": {
        "customfield_14550": null,
        "customfield_12770": null,
        "customfield_11441": "2023-07-13T12:45:00.000+0200",
        "customfield_12772": null,
        "customfield_14444": null,
        "customfield_10120": null,
        "customfield_12941": null,
        "customfield_14445": null,
        "customfield_12940": null,
        "customfield_14446": null,
        "due_date": null,
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
"""
jira_object_1 = json.loads(jira_object_1)
jira_object_1_fields = jira_object_1["fields"]
```

That will give us a dictionary and a convenience name to the fields within it.

Now with your set of key value tuples:

```py
keys = {
     # path and description
    ("fields.customfield_14550", "name-1"),
    ("fields.customfield_12770", "name-2"),
    ("fields.customfield_11441", "name-3"),
    ("fields.customfield_12772", "name-4"),
    ("fields.customfield_14444", "name-5"),
    ("fields.customfield_10120", "name-6"),
    ("fields.customfield_12941", "name-7"),
    ("fields.customfield_14445", "name-8"),
    ("fields.customfield_12940", "name-9"),
    ("fields.customfield_14446", "name-10"),
    ("fields.due_date", "date"),
    ("fields.foo", "bar")
}
```

We can find the corresponding keys and values in the new dictionary.

```py
for key, value in keys:
    value2 = jira_object_1_fields.get(key.split(".")[1])
    if value == value2:
        continue
    print(f"{key}: {value} != {value2}")
```

Comment: I can't seem to use the json dumps or json loads to convert the object. It is a pain. This method would work if I used the api, but I am trying to get it to work with the jira module...

Comment: from jira import JIRA

Comment: Is your issue that the thing you get from jira is not a json string? what does `type(print(jira_object_1 ))` tell you?

Comment: apparently it is a resource and not a dict ( https://jira.readthedocs.io/advanced.html )

Comment: Potentially, what does `jira_object_1.__dict__` look like?

Comment: so, it was a coding issue on my part. the object isn't a dict, but a resource object. Essentially, it looks like object.fields: { custom_fileds: "xxxxx", custom_fields: "xxx"  and so on....} I managed to fix it and get it going without a loop.....